# Better way to get associated model in Django from the parent model in view

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='New York', blank=False, null=False)
    #other fields
```

And in `views.py` I should fetch `users` and `userprofiles` so that I can get it in `home.html`:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def home(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
    context = { 'users': users }
    return render(request, 'users/home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
    //other userprofile data
{% endfor %}
```

Here I am getting the values of `userprofile` in template. But what if I have about 100000 users? Will this be an efficient query? I need to fetch all 100000 users and display them at a time in a single page. For this particular page pagination is not required. Styling makes them appear very small. So the query should get all 100000 users and their profile values. What is the best way to get those values in template?

**Edit**

Now I have used

```
User.objects.filter(is_staff=True).prefetch_related('userprofile')
```

as stated by @Alexander Lekontsev.

By doubt now is how to render this in template? Should I use the above method specified in the question? Or should I use two for loops?

```
{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
    {% for profile in user.userprofile.all %}
        <p>{{ profile.city }}</p>
        //other userprofile data
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This method does not work. What is the correct way?

Comment: What about [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)? It allows you to select userprofiles related to filtered users

Comment: `select_related` should be used from `userprofile` to `user` right? What if I should query from `user` to `userprofile`?

Comment: My bad. It should be [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Thus your query will look like this: `User.objects.filter(is_staff=True).prefetch_related('userprofile')`